# Replace Mr. With Mr in Python function returning error

Tags: python, list, function

im trying to write a function that will look at Mr. and replace it with Mr in a list. however it keeps saying 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'. Ive looked up some things but cant figure it out. Any help is appreciated!

Current Function

```
def remove_abbreviations(abbreviation):
    list(abbreviation)
    words = [abbreviation.replace('Mr.', 'Mr') for w in len(abbreviation)]
```

abbreviation is a list that was generated by reading in a text file and splitting it by white space

Comment: len(abbreviation) will return Len of the abbreviation, which is an int object not iterable.

Comment: I removed that and now it says 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: words = [w.replace('Mr.', 'Mr') for w in abbreviation] # assuming that abbreviation is a list of strings

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It makes it easier for *us* if you include a minimal example of the data you are operating on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can replace the values inside a list.

```
def remove_abbreviations(abbreviation):
    words = [w.replace('Mr.', 'Mr') for w in abbreviation]
    return words

old_list =['Mr.X', 'Mr.Y']
new_list = remove_abbreviations(old_list)
print(new_list)
```

Prints,

```
['MrX', 'MrY']
```

Writing a function is probably overkill,

```
old_list =['Mr.X', 'Mr.Y']
new_list = [w.replace('Mr.', 'Mr') for w in old_list]
print(new_list)
```